# Retrofit nullable params map

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have the interface for retrofit

```
interface ApiInterface {

    @GET
    Observable<okhttp3.ResponseBody> get(@Url String url,
                                         @HeaderMap Map<String, Object> headerMap,
                                         @QueryMap HashMap<String, String> queryMap );
}
```

I call this way, and it works perfectly

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("id","xyz");
apiInterface.get(url,  getHeader(),map)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

but when I pass `null`, it does not work

```
return apiInterface.get(url,  getHeader(),null)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

how pass null for retrofit an interface?

Comment: return apiInterface.get(url,  getHeader(), Collections.emptyMap()) ? Do not pass null when the method argument is a collection.

Comment: @llya  Collections.emptyMap() not work

Comment: what happens if you pass your map object without `map.put("id","xyz");`, remove that line and try.

Comment: @KaranMer it works, but I don't create new HashMap , i need pass null

Comment: that will be an empty map as you have not added any values to it, so blank values will be passed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot pass null basically. Two possible solutions.

1. Either use an empty HashMap<>

   ```
         new HashMap<>()
   ```
2. Write another api call without that field as below.

interface ApiInterface {

```
@GET
Observable<okhttp3.ResponseBody> get(@Url String url,
                                     @HeaderMap Map<String, Object> headerMap,
                                     @QueryMap HashMap<String, String> queryMap );
```

}

interface ApiInterface {

```
@GET
Observable<okhttp3.ResponseBody> get(@Url String url,
                                     @QueryMap HashMap<String, String> queryMap );
```

}

You can find more details you can read here:
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1488
(It is not my post by the way)

Answer (score -1):

You can pass empty Map if you do not want to send any value to your request param. Use the following code.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
apiInterface.get(url,  getHeader(),map)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```